# Trying to remove some columns from a TFS Kanban board

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

One of my users has discovered that 3 new columns were added to the Kanban board. I've never removed a column from a Kanban board before, so I've been researching how this might be done. It looks like I have to use a command line utility named witAdmin. Using what I found I launched the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015 and then entered this command:

```
 witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://ourtfsserver:8080/tfs/Enterprise%20Architecture /p:"Server 2008 Retirement" /n:Task /f:"D:\FileToExportTo.xml"
```

I thought opened the FileToExportTo.xml file, but I couldn't find the column headers that need to be removed, anywhere in it. So, I must have either left something off in the command line, or gave the wrong parameter. What do I need to change, please?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your command line. But it's used to delete redundant state in task.

If you just want to remove some columns from the board. I will give you a more detail steps for your reference:

***Before in the sprint board:***

[image]

***Steps:***

1. Export work item (e.g. task) through WitAdmin command.
2. Delete not used custom state to workflow section
3. [Export ProcessConfiguration process file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?view=azure-devops-2019) through WitAdmin command.
4. Delete the row of state test item in TaskBacklog=>States section. For example:

   `<States>
     <State type="Proposed" value="To Do" />
     <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
     <State type="InProgress" value="Test" />
     <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
   </States>`
5. Import modified work item file and process file to the team project
6. Check the result in web access.

[image]

***After deleted the column:***

[image]

After deleted, the customized test column "Test" is gone, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the former TFS administrator about this issue. He went poking around in TFS 2015 and found an alternative solution. Go to the TFS Team Project, then go to WORK. Make sure you've selected Board and then go to the gear Configuration/Settings. Under the General tab, select "Working with bugs" tab. What he found was someone had selected "Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with tasks". It should be "Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with requirements".

[image: Working with bugs]